# Trigger Azure Function which update the status of a record on blob containers file deletion

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger, azureazure-blob-storage, azure-blob-storage-delete

Use Case : We have a blob container contains CSV files which gets deletes on 24 hours from the creation. On delete event of file would like to call a azure blob trigger function to update the status of respective file row in SQL DB to expired/deleted.

Question: is it possible to achieve this scenario using Azure blob trigger function? if yes i appreciate the reference documents/ your inputs thank you.

Solutions already tried:

https://medium.com/@kvanshika94/connecting-to-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-functions-python-4fefa1adf66b

i need to receive the container and file details as a out parameters to pass as input params of the blob trigger function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created event grid trigger in my environment and got expected results given below.
the way to create event grid trigger function is to create it using Azure portal. Firstly, created a python Event grid trigger function as below

[image]

Then I created an event subscription.

[image]

Using blog trigger function created an event subscription. and then we select an endpoint.
Any further reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100113/eventgridtrigger-azure-function-with-blob-trigger/74188828#74188828).

[image]

Comment: tried this implementation but the function is not triggered, the reason event grid push is not supported by private endpoint pull( function app is in private endpoint)- this is not working :) but the scenario you have given is working for public endpoint